# Why does the puts method behave strangely when used in a thread?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

**SOLUTION:** In .irbc file, put: `IRB.conf[:USE_READLINE] = false`

I am running some ruby code:

```
Thread.new do
 loop do
   a = @queue.pop
   puts "1"
   puts "2"
 end
end
```

When i run this in irb, and queue pops, it print "1", but doesn't print "2" right away. I have to press enter couple of times before it spits out "2". Why is that?

Here's my irb log:

```
>> Thread.new do
?>  loop do
?>    a = @queue.pop
>>    puts "1"
>>    puts "2"
>>  end
>> end
=> #<Thread:0x10ae6d1a0 sleep>
>> @queue << "something random"
1=> #<Queue:0x10aed6420>
>> 
?> 

?> 
?> 
2?>
```

Here's what I get:

```
>> require "thread"
=> true
>> 
?> @queue = Queue.new
=> #<Queue:0x101bc9a60>
>> 
?> Thread.new do
?>  loop do
?>    a = @queue.pop
>>    puts "1 was printed at #{Time.now.to_f}"
>>    puts "2 was printed at #{Time.now.to_f}"
>>  end
>> end
=> #<Thread:0x101bb8058 sleep>
>> 
?> @queue << 42
1 was printed at 1328144684.33667=> #<Queue:0x101bc9a60>
>> 
?> 

?> 
?> 
2 was printed at 1328144686.4642?>
```

Comment: Is your version of Ruby compiled with threading support enabled?

Comment: @andrewdotnich: Why did you remove the OS X lion tag?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: because I could replicate it on Snow Leopard. It's possible that it's a *nix-implementation issue, but it's not Lion-only…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experimented some and found out what is happening. As you might know, two Ruby threads cannot run at the same time; they just switch back and forth quickly.* Normally, if you call `gets`, the calling thread will wait for input, and other threads will continue (because `gets` releases the [GIL](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/05/ruby-threading-futures) ). However, in irb, (at least on Mac OS X) other threads do not continue to execute while it is waiting for input. Example:

```
>> i = 0
=> 0
>> Thread.new { loop { i += 1 } }
=> #<Thread:0x1094d6d68 run>
>> i
=> 234866
>> i
=> 401271
```

If the thread were executing, `i` would be in the millions. (Tested outside irb.) Plus, ruby was using < 1% CPU.

In your example, each time you press enter, the thread gets a split second to execute--enough time to write out a number or a newline. Then ruby switches back to irb's thread, which writes the prompt and waits on input.

* With JRuby, IronRuby, and Rubinius 2.0, multiple threads can run at the same time.

*Edit:* I tested on Windows, and threads keep running there. If you want threads to keep running on Mac, you could save this as, say, sirb.rb (simple irb) and use it instead of irb:

```
$stdout.sync = true
while true
    print "> "
    p(eval gets)
end
```

Note that, unlike irb, it doesn't support a statement spanning multiple lines, nor does it support moving the caret to edit or pressing Up for history (on Mac OS X). Example:

```
> for i in 1..10; print i ** 2, " "; end; puts
1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100 
nil
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest alternative on how I can monitor threads while still being able to input ruby code ( like irb)? Basically, I am trying to log information of each individual thread so I can see how the program behaves working under multiple threads

Comment: @PragmaOnce: I edited my answer to add an alternative to irb. Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Thanks man! When you tested it on Windows, were you using IRB as well or some other ruby shell? Do you think this issue is Mac specific? Will some linux variant work just like windows did?

Comment: Found out a way to fix it. In .irbc file, include "IRB.conf[:USE_READLINE] = false"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting what you're geting. The two numbers are printed in the same millisecond on my machine. (I tried it under 1.8.7 on a Windows machine, and still got that result)

```
require "thread"

@queue = Queue.new

Thread.new do
 loop do
   a = @queue.pop
   puts "1 was printed at #{Time.now.to_f}"
   puts "2 was printed at #{Time.now.to_f}"
 end
end

@queue << 42

$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require "thread"
=> true
irb(main):002:0>
irb(main):003:0* @queue = Queue.new
=> #<Queue:0x1422d80 @que=[], @waiting=[], @mutex=#<Mutex:0x1422d20>>
irb(main):004:0>
irb(main):005:0* Thread.new do
irb(main):006:1*  loop do
irb(main):007:2*    a = @queue.pop
irb(main):008:2>    puts "1 was printed at #{Time.now.to_f}"
irb(main):009:2>    puts "2 was printed at #{Time.now.to_f}"
irb(main):010:2>  end
irb(main):011:1> end
=> #<Thread:0x14a4ec0 run>
irb(main):012:0>
irb(main):013:0* @queue << 42
1 was printed at 1328144503.01272
2 was printed at 1328144503.01272
=> #<Thread:0x14a4ec0 sleep>
```

As I don't have access to OS X Lion, I can't see if it's something to do with Ruby on OS X Lion, but that'd be my suspicion.

Comment: Yes it does. Check my original question. I updated with what I am getting

Comment: Hmmm...not happening for me. That's why I asked what could be possibly wrong. Please check my original question to see what I get.

Comment: @PragmaOnce: Ok, what's your operating system and ruby version? Can you do `irb --version`, `ruby --version`, and go into irb and do `puts RUBY_VERSION`?

Comment: @PragmaOnce: Sorry, I don't have access to that OS. I can't help you any further.

Comment: Thanks anyways. Appreciate it!!